# Can't remove NSURLCredentials from storage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurlcredential

I'm trying to remove credentials from storage when an account is deleted from my app.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] allCredentials];
NSDictionary *dictCopy = [dict copy];
for(NSURLProtectionSpace *key in [dictCopy keyEnumerator])
{
    NSDictionary *value = [dict objectForKey:key];
    NSURLCredential *cred = [value objectForKey:accountLogin];
    if(cred)
        [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] removeCredential:cred forProtectionSpace:key];
}
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] allCredentials]);
```

The remove part gets called for all of the right keys and values but after the method completes, all of the credentials are still intact.  How is that possible?

I've also tried setting new credentials but it seems like they aren't getting recognized either

Comment: any thoughts?  Still wondering about this

Comment: I'm having the same problem – I can't get credentials out of the storage once I've put them in. Calling -removeCredential... seems to have no effect.